# asp.net core 2 Access httpcontext from scoped DI service accessed through hangfire task

Tags: asp.net-core, hangfire

I have an asp.net core2 application with hangfire. Configuration works fine for basic tasks, however now I need to enqueue a background job which accesses the dependency injected httpcontext and dbcontext and I am getting null reference exceptions for httpcontext - I understand why this would be, but...

Can I configure hangfire's enqueue such that the httpcontext and dbcontext from which the task is fired are included with the job? The job is always originally fired from within a controller where the contexts are available. The job is a method on ApprovalService which has _userservice injected into its constructor. _Userservice has the httpContext injected in its constructor.

As I understand it, the graph should be able to resolve this, it is just a question of how...

I dont want to refactor to pass these as arguments as the services are used elsewhere where they do have access to the contexts.

The

My startup is as follows (a lot of things removed for clarity)

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
    private IHostingEnvironment _env;
    public static string connection;

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddCors();
        services.AddMvc(config => {
            config.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(authorizePolicy));
            config.OutputFormatters.OfType<StringOutputFormatter>().Single().SupportedMediaTypes.Add("text/html");
        })                
            .AddJsonOptions(options =>
                {
                    options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultContractResolver();
                    options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
                });

        services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
        connection = Configuration.GetConnectionString("(default)");

        services.AddDbContext<CpContext>(options =>
        {
            options.UseSqlServer(connection);
        });

        services.AddHangfire(configuration => configuration
            .UseSqlServerStorage(connection));

        services.AddScoped<IApprovalService, ApprovalService>();
        services.AddScoped<IUserService, UserService>();
        services.AddScoped<SystemControlService>();
        services.AddScoped<ProjectControlService>();
        services.AddIdentity<CpIdentityUser, IdentityRole>().AddUserManager<cpUserManager>();

        services.AddScoped<ApprovalService>();
        services.AddTransient<IEmailService, EmailService>();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        Log.Information("In configure");
        _env = env;
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            //app.UseBrowserLink();
        }

        app.UseCors(x => x
            .AllowAnyOrigin()
            .AllowAnyMethod()
            .AllowAnyHeader()
            .AllowCredentials());

        app.UseAuthentication();

        app.UseMvc();
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseHangfireDashboard("/hangfire", new DashboardOptions
        {
            Authorization = new[] { new CustomAuthorizeFilter() }
        });
        app.UseHangfireServer();
    }

    public class CustomAuthorizeFilter : IDashboardAuthorizationFilter
    {
        public bool Authorize([NotNull] DashboardContext context)
        {
            var httpcontext = context.GetHttpContext();
            return httpcontext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;
        }
    }
}
```

I fire the job like this (non job version commented and works - hangfire job hangs on nullreference when trying to get userID from the context);

```
[Produces("application/json")]
[Route("api/Approvals")]
public class ApprovalsController : Controller
{
    private readonly CpContext _context;
    private IUserService _userService;
    private IBackgroundJobClient _backgroundJobClient;
    private ApprovalService _approvalService;

    public ApprovalsController(CpContext context, IUserService userService, ApprovalService approvalService, IBackgroundJobClient backgroundJobClient)
    {
        _context = context;
        _userService = userService;
        _approvalService = approvalService;
        _backgroundJobClient = backgroundJobClient;
    }

    public class approvalWrapper
    {
        public int ApprovalId { get; set; }
        public List<string> emailTo { get; set; }
        public List<string> ccTo { get; set; }
        public string ManualApprCode { get; set; }
        public int RequestToId { get; set; }
        public DateTime RequestDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime RequiredDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime ResponseDate { get; set; }
        public string RequestText { get; set; }
        public string ResponseText { get; set; }
        public int ApprovalStatusTypeId { get; set; }
        public int ApprovalItemTypeId { get; set; }
        public int? NcrLinkId { get; set; }
        public int? LotItpDetailLinkId { get; set; }
        public int? LotQtyLinkId { get; set; }
    }

    // POST: api/Approvals/sendRequest
    [HttpPost("sendRequest")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> sendRequest([FromBody] approvalWrapper approvalInfo)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid) return BadRequest(ModelState);
        Approval approval = new Approval()
        {
            RequestById = _userService.User_ID,
            RequestToId = approvalInfo.RequestToId,
            RequestDate = approvalInfo.RequestDate,
            RequiredDate = approvalInfo.RequiredDate,
            RequestText = approvalInfo.RequestText,
            NcrLinkId = approvalInfo.NcrLinkId,
            LotItpDetailLinkId = approvalInfo.LotItpDetailLinkId,
            LotQtyLinkId = approvalInfo.LotQtyLinkId,
            ApprovalItemTypeId = approvalInfo.ApprovalItemTypeId,
            ApprovalStatusTypeId = 5,
        };
        try
        {
            _context.Approval.Add(approval);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.Error(ex, "Error trying to create approval.");
            return StatusCode(422);
        }
        _backgroundJobClient.Enqueue<IApprovalService>(serv => serv.sendRequestEmailAsync(approval.ApprovalId, approvalInfo.emailTo, approvalInfo.ccTo));

        //await _approvalService.sendRequestEmailAsync(approval.ApprovalId, approvalInfo.emailTo, approvalInfo.ccTo);
        return Ok(1);
    }
}

interface IApprovalService
{
    Task<string> getApprovalRequestTextForChecklistItem(int checklistItemId);
    Task<string> getApprovalRequestTextForNCR(int NCRId);
    Task<bool> sendRequestEmailAsync(int apprToRequestID, List<string> emailTo = null, List<string> ccTo = null);
    Task<bool> sendResponseEmailAsync(int apprToRequestID, List<string> emailTo = null, List<string> ccTo = null);
    Task<bool> isApprovalCodeValidAsync(string qryString, int apprToRequestID);
}

public class ApprovalService: IApprovalService
{
    CpContext _context;
    IEmailService _emailService;
    private ProjectControlService _projectControlService;
    private SystemControlService _systemControlService;
    private IUserService _userService;

    public ApprovalService(CpContext context, IEmailService emailService, SystemControlService systemControlService,
        ProjectControlService projectControlService, IUserService userService)
    {
        _context = context;
        _emailService = emailService;
        _userService = userService;
        _systemControlService = systemControlService;
        _projectControlService = projectControlService;
    }

public interface IUserService
{
    int Project_ID { get; }
    int User_ID { get; }

    Task<UserCredDto> AuthenticateAsync(string username, string password);
    HashSet<string> getUserPermsForProject(int userID, int ProjectID);
    IEnumerable<User> GetAll();
    Task<User> GetByIdAsync(int id);
    Task<User> GetUserAsync();
    Task<User> CreateUserAsync(User user, string password);
    Task UpdateAsync(User user, string password = null);
    Task<User> DeleteAsync(int id);
    bool Exists(int id);
    string checkRefreshToken(string refreshToken, UserCredDto tokenOwner, int refreshLifeTime);
    Task<string> getNewRefreshTokenAsync(UserCredDto tokenOwner, int refreshLifeTime = 60);
    string GetUserName();
    Task<UserDto> GetUser();
    ClaimsPrincipal GetClaimsPrincipal();
}

public class UserService : IUserService
{
    private CpContext _context;
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpcontext;


    public UserService(CpContext context, IHttpContextAccessor httpcontext)
    {
        _context = context;
        _httpcontext = httpcontext;
    }
}
```